# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<?php
function consulta () {

global $conexion; 

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$bd = "alumnos";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $bd);

$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM alumnos', $conexion);

// comienza un bucle que leerá todos los registros existentes
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
// $row es un array con todos los campos existentes en la tabla
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "clave del alumno: ".$row['claveAlumno ']."<br>";
    echo "Nombre: ".$row['nombre']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos: ".$row['apellidos']."<br>";
    echo "Fecha de Namiciento:".$row['fNacimiento']."<br>";

} // fin del bucle de instrucciones
mysqli_free_result($result); // Liberamos los registros
mysqli_close($conexion); // Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
echo "<hr>";

}
echo consulta();

?>
```

pero lamentablemente me muestra los siguientes errores

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexionMySQL\resources\actions\conexion.php on
>   line 12
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\conexionMySQL\resources\actions\conexion.php on line
>   15
>
> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\conexionMySQL\resources\actions\conexion.php on line
>   24

Podría por favor ayudar con este error.

Comment: Invierte los parámetros en mysqli_query, es decir: $result = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM alumnos');

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A primera vista , [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) espera como parámetros primero la conexión y luego la consulta
y usted está haciendo lo contrario ,debería ser

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM alumnos' );
```

Comment: Gracias, esa fue la solución, en verdad te lo agradezco, excelente noche