# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php

Este es mi codigo

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
  {     
  require_once "/Paises/php/conexion.php";
  $conexion=conexion();
  session_start(); 
  } 



 ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Tabla Registro Ciudad/Pais</h2>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
        <caption>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevo">
                Agregar nuevo 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
        </caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Apellido</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Telefono</td>
                <td>Editar</td>
                <td>Eliminar</td>
            </tr>

            <?php 

                if(isset($_SESSION['consulta'])){
                    if($_SESSION['consulta'] > 0){
                        $idp=$_SESSION['consulta'];
                        $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono 
                        from gestionelo where id='$idp'";
                    }else{
                        $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono 
                        from gestionelo ";
                    }
                }else{
                    $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono 
                        from gestionelo";
        }

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

                    $datos=$row[0]."||".
                           $row[1]."||".
                           $row[2]."||".
                           $row[3]."||".
               $row[4];

             ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $ver[1] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[2] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[3] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[4] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">

                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
                    onclick="preguntarSiNo('<?php echo $ver[0] ?>')">

                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
        }
             ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que tu pregunta es una de las que más veces se han preguntado aquí y han sido marcadas como duplicada. Revisa tu `$conexion`  que no sea nula, o tu `$sql`, que no tenga ningún error. Esos son los dos posibles motivos del error.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105641/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Comment: No me sirvio ya hice revision pero nada

Comment: Hola por favor adjunta el código de conexion.php para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: haz un echo a la variable sql, lo que te imprima ponla directo en el sql y comprueba que la consulta esté bien

Comment: Voy a subir un link con ambos archivos con el que estoy manejando y con la tabla que sirve + sql

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/jck7wszz5srrp6m/tabladinamica.rar

Answer (score 0):

Haz pasar el código por todos los procesos de validación requeridos. Así sabrás dónde se halla el problema:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    require_once "/Paises/php/conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();

    if ($conexion){
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['consulta'])){
            if($_SESSION['consulta'] > 0){
                $idp=$_SESSION['consulta'];
                $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono
                        from gestionelo where id='$idp'";
            }else{
                $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono
                        from gestionelo ";
            }
        }else{
            $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono
                        from gestionelo";
        }

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        if ($resultado){

/*
  *Hay que agregar este bloque, el cual olvidé tomar 
  *de tu código original
*/
    ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Tabla Registro Ciudad/Pais</h2>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
        <caption>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevo">
                Agregar nuevo 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
        </caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Apellido</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Telefono</td>
                <td>Editar</td>
                <td>Eliminar</td>
            </tr>

<?php

/*Aquí sigue el código que ya había*/

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                $datos=$row[0]."||".
                    $row[1]."||".
                    $row[2]."||".
                    $row[3]."||".
                    $row[4];

?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $ver[1] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[2] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[3] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[4] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">

                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                    onclick="preguntarSiNo('<?php echo $ver[0] ?>')">

                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
            <?php

        }else{
            echo "Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
        }

    }else{

        echo "Error de conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }

}else{

    echo "Error de sesión";
}
```

Comment: Me aparece error en sesion

Comment: @KristianEspitia pues ya sabes donde buscar. No hay realmente sesión activa.

Comment: No nose donde buscar es que no se por que me esta dando errores por que si coloco la tabla sola en una pagina aparte si agarra pero cuando la paso a la pagina me  empieza a botar error

Comment: @KristianEspitia debes revisar la forma e que inicias sesión o bien quitar esto `if(!isset($_SESSION))`  ... eso depende de lo que quieras hacer , yo puse las cosas como las tenías originalmente, estableciendo controles de cada eventualidad.

Comment: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in  me aparece este erorr

Comment: @KristianEspitia quita también esto: `session_start();`

Comment: require_once(..Paises/php/conexion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionelo\Paises\componentes\tabla.php on line 119

Comment: Je, je, ¿ves cómo el código escrito de forma controlada canta los errores de una vez? Te dice claramente que esta ruta esta mal: `/Paises/php/conexion.php` debes revisar si hay una carpeta llamada `Paises` y dentro de ella una llamada `php` y dentro de ella un archivo llamado `conexion.php`  Si existen, indica cuál es la ruta completa y di dónde se encuentra tu script PHP (el del código de la pregunta). Hay un problema con tus rutas.

Comment: Ya revise fue por que borre el session_start(); por que las rutas estan bien

Comment: @KristianEspitia no creo. Ese error: *`require_once(..Paises/php/conexion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory `*  es muy concreto. El que pongas o no la sesión no lo corrije porque dice claramente que ese archivo no existe en esa ruta.

Comment: Ya lo solucione pero al momento de agregar datos no me los  muestra pero si los guarda

Comment: @KristianEspitia ¿cómo agregar datos? En el código que muestras no se agregan datos, se hace un `SELECT` que es para buscar datos que ya existen.

Comment: Pero En esa tabla lo que hace es que busca y a la vez muestra lo datos que se pone como es : Nombre , telefono , email, un boton de eliminar y editar lo cual no aparece

Comment: Quizá la  consulta no devuelve nada, lo puedes probar poniendo después de `$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);`, lo siguiente: `echo "Total filas: ".$resultado->num_rows;` @KristianEspitia

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/723g4iu3671d42p/Captura_de_pantalla_%281%29.png/file

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/s4cwfsa2d987pt5/Captura_de_pantalla_%282%29.png/file

Comment: Mira como debe ser la tabla y  como aparece

Comment: O me regalarias un correo y te envio el codigo ?

Comment: @KristianEspitia en mi código olvidé poner la parte inicial de la tabla (código HTML), quizá sea por eso, revisa la edición de la respuesta, poniendo lo que hay entre `/*
  *Hay que agregar este bloque, el cual olvidé tomar 
  *de tu código original
*/
    ?>` y entre `<?php

/*Aquí sigue el código que ya había*/` Eso debe estar provocando que la tabla no se crea bien.

Comment: O hay una forma de llamar a la carpeta de tabla dinamica y que se muestre en  la pagina que quiero

Comment: No sé lo que quieres decir con eso. En todo caso ya nos alejamos del problema principal que era que la consulta no funcionaba. Cualquier otra cosa la puedes hacer, mediante un modelo `MVC`, mediante `CSS` u otros. Pero como digo, eso es ya otra cuestión.

Comment: Amigos envio Gestionelo que es el dcumento donde estoy trabajando donde en el menu Paises debe de ir la pagina de tabla , y esta el archivo tabladinamica que es el que estoy utilizando + sql estoy manejando por xampp control

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/8dwdkb1ouw0x968/gestionelo.rar/file
http://www.mediafire.com/file/a0mx5iiruhhjxdp/Sql.rar
http://www.mediafire.com/file/jck7wszz5srrp6m/tabladinamica.rar/file

Comment: Habra alguna manera de llamar la carpeta tabla dinamica y que se muestre en la pagina de gestionelo

Comment: No puedo mover la conversacion a un Chat ya que @KristianEspitia no tiene reputacion suficiente para conversar en una sala, asi que recordar ir borrando los comentarios obsoletos para dejar una publicacion limpia y ordenada. Un saludo

Comment: Me pueden escribir a srspit06@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque tienes el $sql dentro del else mientras que 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); fuera.

Intenta:

```
else{
         $sql="SELECT id,nombre,apellido,email,telefono from gestionelo";
         $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     }
```