# Warning: mysqli_query() error

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este error al intentar conectar a la db y verificar el login a la hora de que el usuario inicia secion en la web use este video de referencia 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtMqFFBiwzE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","web");

   if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
     $user = $_POST['username'];
     $pass = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = mysqli_query("select password from user where usuario='$user'");
     $data = $conn->query($sql);
     if ($row = $data) {
       if ($pass=$row['password']) {
         header("loation:home.php");
         exit();

       }else {echo "Password incorrect!";}
    }

   }
```

alguien tiene idea de como solucionar este error?

Comment: Duplicada de [Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105641/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando una mezcla entre el modo orientado a objetos y el de procedimientos. Cambia el query de esta forma mejor:

```
$sql = $conn->query("select password from user where usuario='$user'");
```

**Respuesta corregida:**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","web");

   if ($_POST['login']) {
     $user = "$_POST['username'];
     $pass = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = $conn->query("select password from user where usuario='$user'");

     if ($sql) {
       $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();

       if ($pass=$data['password']) {
         header("loation:home.php");
         exit();

       }else {echo "Password incorrect!";}
    }

   }
```

Este código está asumiento que siempre recibirás un sólo registro de la base de datos, ya que **$data = $sql->fetch_assoc()** usado de esta forma, sólo traerá el primero. Normalmente eso se usa dentro de un bucle para que vaya leyendo todos los registros del resultado.

Comment: y en el if ($row = $data) {} que añado en lugar del $data?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incluir el código completo.