# ¿Por qué está este error : Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Este error sigue apareciendo e intenté ya con varias respuestas de acá pero ninguna me funciona. Esto es lo que tengo

```
       $values = [
         [$empresa, 's'],
         [$codigo, 's']
       ];
       
       $result = mysqli_query($query , $values) or die(mysqli_error($query));

       while ($form = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
       echo " 
           <tr> 
               <td width='150'>".$form['empresa']."</td> 
               <td width='150'>".$form['codigo']."</td> 
               <td width='150'>".$form['id']."</td> 
               <td width='150'></td> 

           </tr> 
             "; 
         }
```

acá me tira el error:
`$result = mysqli_query($query , $values) or die(mysqli_error($query));`

Comment: El problema son esos parámetros que pasas, revisa la doc. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105641/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Comment: gracias por el  primer dato! me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mysqli_query le estás pasando

```
$result = mysqli_query($query, $values) or die(mysqli_error($query));
```

Cuando debería ser

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Se le pasa el identificador de la conexión, de ese modo sabe donde conectarse y donde hacer la consulta. Mismo caso para el mysqli_error, por que revisa el error de esa conexion dicha.

Comment: mmm el eror se repite: "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in" pero con object

Comment: Muestra tu conexion, quizás la palabra no es la que te pase, por que OBVIO, debe ser el link identificador de TU CONEXION

Comment: puse mi propia conexión y pasó lo mismo pero después descubrí que el error venía por otro lado, de todas maneras tu respuesta me ayudó, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cual era el error ? XD

Comment: me faltó especificar que era una array en el html xDDDD sorry recién estoy aprendiendo

Comment: XDDDDDDDDDDDDDD